# How to create DataFrame from fixed-length text file given field lengths?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading fixed positional file. Final result of file is stored in string. I would like to convert string into a `DataFrame` to process further. Kindly help me on this. Below is my code:

Input data:
+---------+----------------------+

|PRGREFNBR|value                 |

+---------+----------------------+

|01       |11 apple     TRUE 0.56|

|02       |12 pear      FALSE1.34|

|03       |13 raspberry TRUE 2.43|

|04       |14 plum      TRUE  .31|

|05       |15 cherry    TRUE 1.4 |

+---------+----------------------+

data position: `"3,10,5,4"`

expected result with default header in data frame:

+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+

|SeqNo|col_0|     col_1|col_2|col_3|

+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+

| 01  |  11 |apple     |TRUE | 0.56|

| 02  |  12 |pear      |FALSE| 1.34|

| 03  |  13 |raspberry |TRUE | 2.43|

| 04  |  14 |plum      |TRUE | 1.31|

| 05  |  15 |cherry    |TRUE | 1.4 |

+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+

Comment: Can you clarify the term "items"?

Comment: val FixedLengths = "3,10,5,4";

val items =(FixedLengths.split("\\s*,\\s*")).toList ;

val size1=items.size;

val file = "C:/Users/phadpa01/Desktop/PositionalFile/positionaldata.txt"

Comment: Please update your question with the above codes and some sample data so that others can help you too and you reach to your solution quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fixed-position file (say `input.txt`):

```
11 apple     TRUE 0.56

12 pear      FALSE1.34 

13 raspberry TRUE 2.43 

14 plum      TRUE 1.31 

15 cherry    TRUE 1.4
```

and the length of every field in the input file as (say `lengths`):

```
3,10,5,4
```

you could create a DataFrame as follows:

```
// Read the text file as is
// and filter out empty lines
val lines = spark.read.textFile("input.txt").filter(!_.isEmpty)

// define a helper function to do the split per fixed lengths
// Home exercise: should be part of a case class that describes the schema
def parseLinePerFixedLengths(line: String, lengths: Seq[Int]): Seq[String] = {
  lengths.indices.foldLeft((line, Array.empty[String])) { case ((rem, fields), idx) =>
    val len = lengths(idx)
    val fld = rem.take(len)
    (rem.drop(len), fields :+ fld)
  }._2
}

// Split the lines using parseLinePerFixedLengths method
val lengths = Seq(3,10,5,4)
val fields = lines.
  map(parseLinePerFixedLengths(_, lengths)).
  withColumnRenamed("value", "fields") // <-- it'd be unnecessary if a case class were used
scala> fields.show(truncate = false)
+------------------------------+
|fields                        |
+------------------------------+
|[11 , apple     , TRUE , 0.56]|
|[12 , pear      , FALSE, 1.34]|
|[13 , raspberry , TRUE , 2.43]|
|[14 , plum      , TRUE , 1.31]|
|[15 , cherry    , TRUE , 1.4 ]|
+------------------------------+
```

That's what you may have had already so let's unroll/destructure the nested sequence of fields into columns

```
val answer = lengths.indices.foldLeft(fields) { case (result, idx) =>
  result.withColumn(s"col_$idx", $"fields".getItem(idx))
}
// drop the unnecessary/interim column
scala> answer.drop("fields").show
+-----+----------+-----+-----+
|col_0|     col_1|col_2|col_3|
+-----+----------+-----+-----+
|  11 |apple     |TRUE | 0.56|
|  12 |pear      |FALSE| 1.34|
|  13 |raspberry |TRUE | 2.43|
|  14 |plum      |TRUE | 1.31|
|  15 |cherry    |TRUE | 1.4 |
+-----+----------+-----+-----+
```

*Done!*

Comment: if data frame contains only fixed length records the I am able to use your function. Some of the data frame I have with Sequence number then kindly let me know how to use your function.    +---- +------------------------------+
|SeqNo|fields                        |
+-----+------------------------------+
|  01 |[11 , apple     , TRUE , 0.56]|
|  02 |[12 , pear      , FALSE, 1.34]|
|  03 |[13 , raspberry , TRUE , 2.43]|
|  04 |[14 , plum      , TRUE , 1.31]|
|  05 |[15 , cherry    , TRUE , 1.4 ]|
+-----+------------------------------+

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the dataframe to it?

Comment: I have added new input and output format of dataframe.

Comment: need to split only second field

Comment: I am trying to combining both column and spliting records and created array of string first field is "SEQNo" and second one is actual Data. After splitting I am trying to actual data I want to merge it in to one dataframe.

Comment: def parseLinePerFixedLengths(line: String, lengths: Seq[Int]): Seq[String] =
  {
    
     val data=line.split("\\|")
      val positionaldata = data(1)
      var x = ("", data)
      println(positionaldata)
      lengths.indices.foldLeft((line, Array.empty[String])) 
      { case ((rem, fields), idx) =>
      val len = lengths(idx)
      val fld = rem.take(len)
    
       (rem.drop(len), fields :+ fld)
      
      }._2
      
  }

Comment: after combining dataset look like :
|11|11 apple     TRUE 0.56|
|12|12 pear      FALSE1.34|
|13|13 raspberry TRUE 2.43|
|14|14 plum      TRUE  .31|
+-------------------------+