# How to read line with comma-separated fields from file?

Tags: scala

I have task to read a positional file. I am able to read positional file with hard-coded data length in code but my task is to read data lengths from external file.

```
val lengths = Seq(3,10,5,4) // <-- I'd like to read it from an external file
```

Comment: what do you mean by positional file? you mean file which contain data representing some positions??

Comment: Input file -11 apple     TRUE 0.56

12 pear      FALSE1.34 

13 raspberry TRUE 2.43 

14 plum      TRUE 1.31 

15 cherry    TRUE 1.4                                                                           
and the length of every field in the input file as (say lengths):

3,10,5,4

Comment: fst field having data length of 3 ,second 10, third  and fourth 4 like wise

Comment: so, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually I need to read the fixed width file. with the help of above code I am able to achieve that one. above code is generic one I need to make it as dynamic only you need to pass input file and position of the file. Any way input file is parameterized only need to make length of the file as parameterised. In stead of hardcode value I want to read it from file

Answer (score 1):

Say, you have a file with the following content (that corresponds to the positions):

```
$ cat positions.csv
3,10,5,4
```

In Scala, you could read the file as follows:

```
val lengths = scala.io.Source.
  fromFile("positions.csv").
  getLines.
  take(1).
  toArray.
  head.
  split(",").
  map(_.toInt).
  toSeq
scala> lengths.foreach(println)
3
10
5
4
```

Comment: Hi Jacek I already did same thing but result is not as expected because as you answered in previous question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992531/how-to-create-dataframe-from-fixed-length-text-file-given-field-lengths " there is lengths has been hardcoaded I would like to read those length from file.here it gives array[string] but required seq[int]

Comment: How about now? Made it seq of ints