# Spark Scala : How to read fixed record length File

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a simple question.

“How to read Files with Fixed record length?” i have 2 fields in the record- name & state.

File Data-

John  OHIO
VictorNEWYORK
Ron   CALIFORNIA

File Layout-

Name String(6);

State String(10);

I just want to read it and create a DataFrame from this file. Just to elaborate more for example on “fixed record length”- if you see since “OHIO” is 4 characters length, in file it is populated with 6 trailing spaces “OHIO      “

The record length here is 16.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 0):

Read your input file:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile('your_file_path')
```

Then use substring to split the fields and then convert RDD to Dataframe using toDF().

```
val df = rdd.map(l => (l.substring(0, 6).trim(), l.substring(6, 16).trim()))
  .toDF("Name","State")

df.show(false)
```

Result:

```
+------+----------+
|Name  |State     |
+------+----------+
|John  |OHIO      |
|Victor|NEWYORK   |
|Ron   |CALIFORNIA|
+------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi, so everything has to be first treated as string as we are essentially applying substring function and say if we have any decimals/date/timestamp fields, we need to cast them to their respective formats. Is that right?

Comment: Yes of course!! The fields has to be cast to their respective formats other than strings.

Comment: You can also refer this - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992531/how-to-create-dataframe-from-fixed-length-text-file-given-field-lengths`